# Optimization and performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Dashboard to display data from stored procedure,
Stored procedure contains calculations for data to be display in dashboard, I am getting an performance issue while executing the stored procedure, so I decided to run the SP in background and decided to dump data in a physical table, after that i can directly fetch data from this table, but again millions data again coming there I will get performance I am not getting a way to solve this kindly help me with this.

Comment: Can you give us some more context? What is the code for the stored procedure? What do the tables look like? What indexes are there?

Comment: In stored procedure I have calculated assessment for employee, there is an calculation  for each employe based on specific period like year or month. And also we have a logic like manager may report to its higher manager so for that hierarchy should also be maintain when storing data in physical  table.i am passing year,deptid,managerid, as parameter to stored procedure. I am not getting any idea how to store this data in physical table, and if it is store how to fetch again those particular data if new data came or old data may updated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the amount of data the dashboard is trying to process.

Since it's okay for you to dump the output on a physical table, simply create an aggregate version of that table.  For example instead of having millions of records, you can group by country, department, employee, etc then dump the output in a physical table instead.  Usually we group the transactions into per day, or in other worlds 1 row per transaction day or GROUP BY CAST(transaction_date AS VARCHAR(12)).

Better yet, if it is possible, modify the stored procedure to return only a few rows of data that is already aggregated.

At least in the place we work in, we call that "reporting tables" and it only contains few thousand rows that drive the dashboards.   So we have an SP.. let's say "usp_Report" that is used by the dashboard.  It does two things **(1)** update the "reporting table" in aggregate form **(2)** return the data found in the "reporting table".  The update the data portion only happens per day/hour so we program this change frequency control within the stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you earl, but in my stored procedure one I should keep track that manager is reporting to a manager ,like admin is reporting to an admin hierarchy way, like wise I am calculating those data doing assessment , when stored procedure is calculating its take lot of time to execute and dashboard keep loading. I am passing managerid,deptid,year as a parameter to calculate data for manager for those employee which are reporting to that manager, and after that I need to dump those data into physical table,and also update frequently when new data came, please provide some more logic.

Comment: Well you can pre-generate parts of the data before hand if it is not possible to simply pre-generate everything in advance.  If the problem is calculations, you can try to identify the "slow areas" then if it is possible to dump the answers in advance somewhere (let's say physical table).  Your SP simply uses (JOINS) to that pre-calculated table to speed things up.   The update frequency of that table is up to you - like you only update it once a day.  The data is not real-time but in most cases in reporting, you don't need the most update report and a 1 day delay is reasonable.